# Storing iot data in mongodb using nodejs after batching the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query

I want to store my iot data in mongodb, currently I have over 300 iot devices sending data in every 15 seconds.

My DB schema for the same is :-

```
A DEVICE COLLECTION:
_id : ObjectId()
name: String
description : String



A VARIABLES COLLECTION:
_id : ObjectId()
name : String // eg. humidity, temp, windspeed
device : ref(device_collection)


A VALUES COLLECTION
variable: ref(variables collection)
value : number,float
timestamp : date
```

### What I intend to learn

I want to store the incoming data in the mongodb in such a way that when a data arrives all the variables in the JSON payload gets extracted from it, and then I check in the db whether or not this variable is present or not and then insert in the variables collection using nodejs.

After that I want to insert the value for the corresponding variable in the value collection with the incoming timestamp.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated, also if any changes are needed to the db schema which I have mentioned please mention. Thank you

Comment: Why do want to store it in 3 collections - If you have a single collection what wrong do you see?

Comment: Managing data in separate collections can be easier, especially when it comes to tasks like adding or removing fields, or applying updates to specific subsets of data. With a single collection, these operations can become more complex and error-prone.
In a single collection I'll have to store data this way, which can in certain case cross the threshold of 16mb limit.
{
  "device_id": "x",
  "time": ISODate("2022-05-12T14:30:00.000Z"),
  "data": [
    {
      "variable": "temperature",
      "value": 25.6
    }
    {
      "variable": "humidity",
      "value": 55.3
    }
  ]
}